# Updating UILabel Colors based on RSSI Values

Tags: ios, swift, label, uilabel, rssi

I am developing an App using BLE to connect to a Microcontroller.
I currently have all that up and running, also to read the RSSI from the BLE link. I am able to display the RSSI fine, to determine the signal strength. But I would like design the label to change colors depending on the signal strength. 0 to -30 (green), -30 to -60(yellow), and -60 to -90(red). I am fairly new to swift. But I have made a Range test view controller.

Obviously my code will just update the color one time. There might be something very simple I'm missing, I just can't quite figure it out. Also, probably a while loop, or for-in would solve this. But so far I haven't been able to get it right.

Anyway if anyone has tips on what route I should take, that would be greatly appreciated!

**Here is the code:**

```
 @IBOutlet weak var RSSILabel: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var deviceLabel: UILabel!

 var timer = Timer()
 var progressHUD: MBProgressHUD?

 func serialDidChangeState() {

 }

 func serialDidDisconnect(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) 
 {

 }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()     
     if (serial?.isReady)! {         
     deviceLabel.text = serial?.connectedPeripheral!.name
     serial?.readRSSI()
     readRssiTimer()
     showRssiInLabel()
     }
}

 func readRssiTimer() {        
     self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: { (Timer) in
         serial?.readRSSI()})
 }

 func showRssiInLabel(){
     self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: { (Timer) in
         self.RSSILabel.text = serial?.realtimeRSSI.stringValue})

       if (serial?.self.realtimeRSSI.intValue)! > -40 {
         RSSILabel.textColor = UIColor.green

         RSSILabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: CGFloat(22))
         self.view.addSubview(RSSILabel)

     } else if (serial?.realtimeRSSI.intValue)! <= -40 && (serial?.realtimeRSSI.intValue)! > -70 {
         RSSILabel.textColor = UIColor.yellow

         RSSILabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: CGFloat(22))
         self.view.addSubview(RSSILabel)
     } else if (serial?.realtimeRSSI.intValue)! <= -70 && (serial?.realtimeRSSI.intValue)! > -90 {
         RSSILabel.textColor = UIColor.red

         RSSILabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: CGFloat(22))
         self.view.addSubview(RSSILabel)
     }     
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have your UILabel in the Storyboard defined as well in your ViewController as `@IBOutlet weak var RSSILabel: UILabel!` means you didn't created RSSILabel programmatically. That means you don't need to do         `self.view.addSubview(RSSILabel)`. Also you can avoid setting the font family each time for every if case as they all have the same. And probably can avoid having `serial?` which at some point might be nil, so better to check it since you declare it optional and then play with it by saying to the compiler you know it's not nil with `serial!`. Also changes to UI should happen in the main thread and might be that you are not in the main thread while changing a UILabel color, so I putted there the `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` block

This should work if you are debugging check and the color should be able to change anyway:

```
func showRssiInLabel(){
        if serial != nil {
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: { (Timer) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.RSSILabel.text = serial!.realtimeRSSI.stringValue
                }
            })

            var labelColor: UIColor = UIColor.green

            if (serial!.self.realtimeRSSI.intValue)! > -40 {
                labelColor = UIColor.green
            } else if (serial!.realtimeRSSI.intValue)! <= -40 && (serial!.realtimeRSSI.intValue)! > -70 {
                labelColor = UIColor.yellow
            } else if (serial!.realtimeRSSI.intValue)! <= -70 && (serial!.realtimeRSSI.intValue)! > -90 {
                labelColor = UIColor.red
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                RSSILabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: CGFloat(22))
                RSSILabel.textColor = labelColor
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the respond! I got it to work now. I can see now that my code needed some cleaning. I simply called the showRssiInLabel function, in my readrssi timer. Thank you!

Comment: @Wolfgang probably either accept this as correct answer or post the correct answer so we can see that the question is closed and solved in future :) Nice job!